# Изменение цвета выделенного текста в UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

Доброго времени суток.
кто-нибудь может подсказать.
Нужно чтоб когда пользователь выделил текст в UITextView и нажал на кнопку выделенная часть окрасилась в выбранный цвет.
Clear возвращает цвет умолчанию (черный) 
Большое спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Выкладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример решения. Сохраняем первоначальные атрибуты, затем их восстанавливаем при сбросе. Переключаем свойство `scrollEnabled` и восстанавливаем `selectedRange`, чтобы предотвратить прокручивание текста в конец при его вставке.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *redButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    NSDictionary *_attributesBackup;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _attributesBackup = [_textView.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:nil inRange:NSMakeRange(0, _textView.text.length)];
}

- (IBAction)applyRed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSRange selectedRange = _textView.selectedRange;

    if (selectedRange.length > 0) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:_textView.attributedText];
        [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:selectedRange];
        _textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        _textView.attributedText = text;
        _textView.selectedRange = selectedRange;
        _textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)reset:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSRange selectedRange = _textView.selectedRange;
    _textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text attributes:_attributesBackup];
    _textView.selectedRange = selectedRange;
    _textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

@end
```